# What escapes " and & in setAttribute/getAttribute?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, double-quotes

If I use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to set some string containing a double quote (or an ambiguous ampersand), and use [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) afterwards, nothing breaks and I get the same string – some automatic mechanism prudently cares for escaping the attribute value.

```js
const e = document.createElement('i');
e.setAttribute('a', 'the "a" & b');

console.log( 'get attribute:', e.getAttribute('a') );
console.log( 'actual markup:', e.outerHTML.match(/a="(.+)"/)[1] );
```

Is this the browser preemptively caring by itself?

Reading the [DOM spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-setattribute), I can’t infer from the given steps which mechanism automatically ensures proper escaping inside the attribute value (if the given value contains otherwise invalid characters).

It’s just faintly disconcerting not knowing who or what is the thoughtful benefactor – ought to be specified somewhere.

Comment: HTML escapes are totally irrelevant when you set element attribute values via the DOM API. The HTML has already been parsed. What counts in your JavaScript code is **JavaScript syntax**, not HTML syntax.

Comment: @Pointy, it’s still becoming an HTML attribute value inside the live DOM, whereby leaving the JS domain and getting parsed, like an entire element being added (along its attributes).

Comment: No, no no. It is not an "HTML attribute value inside the DOM". It is a **DOM attribute value** inside the DOM. The HTML source text is parsed to **create** the DOM.  Once that parsing is complete, the original HTML is irrelevant.

Comment: Don't forget that HTML is just a human-friendly language to insert and extract data into a computer memory. DOM and HTML can be mapped to each other but they're essentially different things.

Answer (score 1):

The `outerHTML` is actually a HTML serialized version:

> Reading the value of outerHTML returns a string containing an HTML serialization of the element and its descendants.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

So in that case double quotes inside double qoutes are HTML escaped. Seems totally proper since otherwise you will have a broken HTML.

The properly escaped HTML could be used further:

```js
const e = document.createElement('i');
e.setAttribute('a', 'the "a" & b');

const div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = e.outerHTML;
const attr = div.querySelector('i').getAttribute('a');
console.log(attr);
```

Also as properly noticed @Pointy in the comments:

> the "outer HTML" text is created from the DOM, without regard to the original HTML that created the (now modified) DOM.

Comment: Right: the "outer HTML" text is created *from the DOM*, without regard to the original HTML that created the (now modified) DOM.

Comment: Not that there is original HTML in the first place. The DOM was created with JS DOM methods.